Edge is slightly diagonal and not aligned with its arrowhead in Cytoscape.js
So I have this topology map where the edges (specifically edge1, edge6, edge5, and edge10) are slightly diagonal and does not align properly with its arrow head as shown on the image.
I don't understand why it is displayed the way it is now, below is the code for it. Would like to ask on how to resolve this styling issue? Below is the full script for reference.
<script>
    var cy = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById('cy'), // container to render in
        elements: [
            // Define the nodes
            { data: { id: 'node1', label: 'NODE 1' } },
            { data: { id: 'node2', label: 'NODE 2' } },

            // Define the edges
            { data: { source: 'node1', target: 'node2', id: 'edge1' } },
            { data: { source: 'node1', target: 'node2', id: 'edge2' } },
            { data: { source: 'node1', target: 'node2', id: 'edge3' } },
            { data: { source: 'node1', target: 'node2', id: 'edge4' } },
            { data: { source: 'node1', target: 'node2', id: 'edge5' } },
            { data: { source: 'node2', target: 'node1', id: 'edge6' } },
            { data: { source: 'node2', target: 'node1', id: 'edge7' } },
            { data: { source: 'node2', target: 'node1', id: 'edge8' } },
            { data: { source: 'node2', target: 'node1', id: 'edge9' } },
            { data: { source: 'node2', target: 'node1', id: 'edge10' } }
        ],
        layout: {
            name: 'grid',
            spacingFactor: 2,
            rows: 1,
            cols: 2,
        },
        style: [
            {
                selector: 'node',
                style: {
                    'shape': 'rectangle',
                    'padding': 0,
                    'height': 300,
                    'width': 200,
                    'border-width': 2,
                    'border-color': 'black'
                }
            },
            {
                selector: 'edge',
                style: {
                    'width': 5,
                    'arrow-scale': 1.5,
                    'text-margin-y': -20,
                    'label': 'data(id)',
                    'line-color': '#000',
                    'target-arrow-color': '#000',
                    "curve-style": "straight",
                    'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    cy.fit();

    // Adjust edge positions
    const spacing = 15;
    cy.batch(() => {
        const edgesFromSource = cy.edges('[source="node1"]');
        const edgesFromTarget = cy.edges('[source="node2"]');
        const totalEdges = Math.max(edgesFromSource.length, edgesFromTarget.length);

        edgesFromSource.forEach((edge, i) => {
            const offset = (i - (totalEdges / 2)) * spacing;
            edge.style({
                'source-endpoint': `0% ${15 + offset}%`,
                'target-endpoint': `-200% ${15 + offset}%`,
            });
        });

        edgesFromTarget.forEach((edge, i) => {
            const offset = (i - (totalEdges / 2)) * spacing;
            edge.style({
                'source-endpoint': `0% ${15 + offset}%`,
                'target-endpoint': `200% ${15 + offset}%`
            });
        });
    });
</script>

